# Where to find ArcGIS service url and how to create one? How upload and view content from the server

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I am new to ArcGIS. I would like to know where I could find the service URL to list all the items in the MyContents tab which could be found by logging into my organization's ArcGIS URL. I want to do this using the Javascript or Rest API provided by ArcGIS.

I was able to get Token from ArcGIS using

**https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token**

this URL.

When I try to upload a file to one of the sample servers using Code, I am not able to do it. It works in postman though.

These are the code that I used for uploading a file to a sample server which failed.

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/DamageAssessment/FeatureServer/uploads/upload",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        data: {
            "f": "json",
            "file": "C:/Users/georgy.f/Downloads/Screenshot_20190422-114420.jpg",
            "description": "descrioption",
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Another code for uploading that I tried.

```
var uploadsettings = {
        "async": false,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/DamageAssessment/FeatureServer/uploads/upload",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
        "data": form
        {
            "f": "json",
            "file": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg",
            "description": "descrioption",
        }
    }

    $.ajax(uploadsettings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

My aim is to list all the MapViews and SceneViews available in my organization.

Also, will I be able to view BIM models in ArcGIS using Javascript or REST API by somehow uploading it to ArcGIS server?